# Postgres not installing properly on my windows

Tags: windows, postgresql

I downloaded Postgres 12.2 a couple of days ago, when installing it could not install fully at a point it said database cluster installation failed. I have tried all I could but to no avail. I really need help so I can continue on my project. A screenshot of the error can be seen

[image: here].

Answer (score 1):

Check in enviroment variables if you don't have incorrect
value for `COMSPEC` ending with trailing semicolon, instead

`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`

`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;`

Comment: did all that but it still didn't work. But when i tried an older version it worked perfectly well. Also a friend told me it was built for servers and not laptps

Comment: That worked perfectly. I had my COMPSEC pointing to the wrong path.